# Whats the difference between a frame and an envelope in rabbitmq-c?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-c

What is the difference between a frame and an envelope in the context of rabbitmq-c.  The examples seem to use them interchangeably, and its not clear what the difference is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A frame (or `amqp_frame_t`) is an AMQP protocol level construct. It represents a unit of transmission over the network can contain a number of different payloads.

An envelope (`amqp_envelope_t`) is a complete received message. An envelope is usually constructed from 3 or more frames. (One method, one header, and one or more body frames).

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  So i noticed in the example code that if the message doesn't come up with a thumbs up you can do a amqp_simple_wait_frame to see the results and some status.  Is that a separate thing?  If the message comes fine, does that frame still exist?  Or is that frame a reply from the rabbitmq broker with information @alanxz

Comment: If `amqp_consume_message` is successful, you do not need to to use `amqp_simple_wait_frame` to get further information.